# Stuck on php8.1 when downgrading to php7.4

Tags: php, debian, apache2

I upgraded the php version on my Apache server running on Debian (buster) from 7.3 to 8.1. Due to an older Nextcloud installation I had to downgrade to php7.4. The downgrade worked well following instructions like [this](https://hostappraiser.com/downgrade-php-8-0-to-7-4-on-ubuntu/), but the server is still reporting it is on the previous version 8.1.13. I placed a simple `phpversion()` file to check out the server version and the Nextcloud installation is complaining of the incorrect version. Is this a cache issue or some configuration file which has to be modified manually?

- CLI: `php -v` returns `PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2022 11:35:02) ( NTS )`
- `php -c /etc/php/apache2/php.ini -v` reads `PHP 7.4.33`
- `update-alternatives --config php` shows `*  2  /usr/bin/php7.4  74  manual mode`
- Added php7.4 module via `sudo a2enmod php7.4`
- Removed all other php modules via `sudo a2dismod phpX.Y`
- `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ looks like this:`

`access_compat.load autoindex.load mime.load reqtimeout.load alias.conf     deflate.conf mpm_prefork.conf rewrite.load alias.load deflate.load mpm_prefork.load setenvif.conf auth_basic.load dir.conf negotiation.conf setenvif.load authn_core.load dir.load negotiation.load socache_shmcb.load authn_file.load env.load php7.4.conf ssl.conf authnz_external.load filter.load php7.4.load ssl.load authz_core.load headers.load proxy.conf status.conf authz_host.load http2.conf proxy_fcgi.load status.load authz_user.load http2.load proxy.load unique_id.load autoindex.conf mime.conf reqtimeout.conf`

phpinfo readout can be [found here](https://lin.us.com/phpinfo.php)

Comment: Debian Buster shipped with PHP 7.3, so it's unclear how you had PHP 7.1, 7.4 or 8.1. You need to add more information to your question, because there is more going on that you have not properly described.

Comment: Which modules is enabled in Apache?

Comment: I supplemented the question after the above comments. The previous version was indeed 7.3 now that I looked at the options with `update-alternatives --config php`

Comment: Found that [Apache2Handler is renamed to php_module from php7_module in PHP 8.0](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/mod_php-rename), but when I ran `grep -r php_module` in `/etc/apache2` I only found files in the mods_avalable directory:

```mods-available/php8.0.load:LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so
mods-available/php8.1.load:LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.1.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Even how I dislike answering my own question, I did find a way out of this problem. I ran

`apt purge '^php8.1.*'`

,restarted the server and got an earlier version of php running. It would still be interesting to know *why* the server chose the latest version and not the one it was oppose to point to via `update-alternatives --config php`.

Answer (score 0):

For me I also had to disable the php8.1-fpm configuration file

```
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm
```

and then reload apache2

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: This is probably a cleaner way of doing it, by disabling `php8.1-fpm` which configuration can be found in the `apache2/conf-available` folder.